# Inner Join - Separate Columns

Tags: mysql, join, hyperlink, inner-join

I'm trying to link 2 tables together containing multiple columns. For example I have a table called '**wp_users**' which I would like to use as the main table, and the other table called '**CD2015_Occurrences**'

I want to link '**wp_users**' [*EMAIL*] to **CD2015_Occurrences**' [*EMAIL*] which is simple but I would like to then add inner joins.

So it would look something like this

**Email   | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |**

email1 |  2   | 4    | 5   | 6

email2  | 4   | 5    | 6  |  0

etc...

Table contents of '**CD2015_Occurrences**' are *Email*, *Quarter*, *Total*

I need to somehow link them by email to wp_users and have 4 separate columns for each quarter.

I'm probably **WELL OFF** but here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    Select a.user_email
FROM wp_users AS a
INNER JOIN a.email
ON CD2015_Occurrences.email as b (SELECT quarter AS Q1 FROM CD2015_Occurrences where email = a.email and quarter = 'q1')
INNER JOIN a.email
ON CD2015_Occurrences.email as b (SELECT quarter AS Q2 FROM CD2015_Occurrences where email = a.email and quarter = 'q2')
INNER JOIN a.email
ON CD2015_Occurrences.email as b (SELECT quarter AS Q3 FROM CD2015_Occurrences where email = a.email and quarter = 'q3')
INNER JOIN a.email
ON CD2015_Occurrences.email as b (SELECT quarter AS Q4 FROM CD2015_Occurrences where email = a.email and quarter = 'q4')
```

any ideas if this is possible and how?
Many thanks
Max

Comment: what do the values 2, 4, 5, 6 mean? are these no. of times the email occurred in the respective quarter? what is the name of date field in occurrence table?

Comment: apologies, there just numbers that users have in putted. I don't have a date field that you are referring to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT users.email,
   SUM(IF(occurences.quarter='q1',occurences.total,0)) Q1,
   SUM(IF(occurences.quarter='q2',occurences.total,0)) Q2,
   SUM(IF(occurences.quarter='q3',occurences.total,0)) Q3,
   SUM(IF(occurences.quarter='q4',occurences.total,0)) Q4
FROM wp_users users
LEFT JOIN CD2015_Occurrences occurrences
ON users.email = occurrences.email
GROUP BY users.email
```

Comment: wow...many thanks for your super quick reply, I've tried your statement, it generates the query but unfortunately all the totals come back as '0' except the 1 row which seems to of added up all the rows together

Comment: Apologies - IT WORKING...many thanks...its taken me forever trying to figure this out! thank you for all your help!!

Comment: You are welcome! good luck with your project! (I guess you should redesign your database schema (email - is a bad key, and `q1, q2, q3,q4` - are bad values (it should be numbers Month, Year or dates))

Comment: Thank you!...I completely agree! I'm just trying to deal with the data they have sent across and make the best of what I've been given.